# Conclusion about conjugacy classes of $\pi$-complements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $\pi$ be a set of primes, and let $N$ have a single conjugacy class of $\pi$-complements and these are nilpotent. If $H^G / N$ is a $\pi$-group, then $H^G$ also has a single conjugacy class of nilpotent $\pi$-complements.

Why that?

Comment: It is not really clear what $H^G$ is, but if $H^G/N$ is a $\pi$-group, then all $\pi$-complements of $H^G$ are contained in $N$, and they are conjugate in $N$ (and hence in $H^G$) and nilpotent by assumption.

Comment: Yes, I think this anwsers my question. Regarding $H^G$ it is $H^G = \langle H^g : g \in G \rangle$.